# Call setup_data from parent class

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

**Backround**

I was reading this excellent answer on how to place self adjusting text into bars: [Resizeable text grobs inside bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319229/ggplot2-geom-text-resize-with-the-plot-and-force-fit-text-within-geom-bar)

After reading a bit on  `ggproto` and especially the vignette on [Extending ggplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html) I was wondering why the author had to define the `setup_data` routine as follows:

```
GeomFit <- ggproto("GeomFit", GeomRect,
               setup_data = function(data, params) {
                 data$width <- data$width %||%
                   params$width %||% (resolution(data$x, FALSE) * 0.9)
                 transform(data,
                           ymin = pmin(y, 0), ymax = pmax(y, 0),
                           xmin = x - width / 2, xmax = x + width / 2, width = NULL
                 )
               })
```

Because this is essentially a copy paste from `ggplot2::GeomBar`:

```
GeomBar$setup_data
# <ggproto method>
#   <Wrapper function>
#     function (...) 
# f(...)

#   <Inner function (f)>
#     function (data, params) 
# {
#     data$width <- data$width %||% params$width %||% (resolution(data$x, 
#         FALSE) * 0.9)
#     transform(data, ymin = pmin(y, 0), ymax = pmax(y, 0), xmin = x - 
#         width/2, xmax = x + width/2, width = NULL)
# }
```

So I thought I could replace this simply by:

```
GeomFit <- ggproto("GeomFit", GeomRect,
                   setup_data = function(self, data, params)
                      ggproto_parent(GeomBar, self)$setup_data(data, params))
```

This approach works, but I have my doubts whether this may lead to some unwanted behaviour simply becasue the parent class of `GeomFit` is `GeomRect` and *not* `GeomBar`.

**Question**

Is it ok (in the sense of: there are no conditions where this may cause a problem) to use `ggproto_parent` to call a function from a class which is not the parent class of my `ggproto` object? Why does `ggproto_parent` have a `parent` argument in the first place? Shouldn't the parent be anyways determined by the second argument of `ggproto`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not involved in the `ggplot2` package's development, but I'll take a stab at this since it's been a week & no one else has posted so far...

Below are the relevant function definitions I copied off ggplot2's [GitHub page](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/1c09bae2aa24320bcb4891c664cccc16efc86a8a/R/ggproto.r):

```
ggproto_parent <- function(parent, self) {
  structure(list(parent = parent, self = self), class = "ggproto_parent")
}

`$.ggproto_parent` <- function(x, name) {
  res <- fetch_ggproto(.subset2(x, "parent"), name)
  if (!is.function(res)) {
    return(res)
  }

  make_proto_method(.subset2(x, "self"), res)
}
```

From the first function, we can deduce that `ggproto_parent(GeomBar, self)` in this case would return a list of two items, `list(parent = GeomBar, self = self)` (where self resolves to `GeomFit`). This list is passed to the second function as `x`.

The second function then searches within the `x[["parent"]]` for a method corresponding to the given name, in this case `setup_data` (`fetch_ggproto`), and associates it with `x[["self"]]` if the function in question includes a `self` parameter (`make_proto_method`).

Neither function checks for the parent of `GeomFit` (which can be accessed at `GeomFit$super()`), so I don't think having `GeomBar` instead of `GeomRect` in `ggproto_parent()` really matters.

---

That said, I would probably have used something like this:

```
GeomFit <- ggproto("GeomFit", GeomRect,
                   setup_data = .subset2(GeomBar, "setup_data"))
```

or this:

```
GeomFit <- ggproto("GeomFit", GeomRect,
                   setup_data = environment(GeomBar$setup_data)$f)
```

Which make for shorter code.

Comment: That's what I call an excellent answer. Thank you so much. It does not only answer my question but gave me very useful insight, which I was not yet aware, in particular the non dispatching form of `[[` aka `.subset2` and how to access the `setup_data` via an evironment. Once more, world class answer! +1 (more if I could ;))