# Extending ggplot with own geoms: Adapt default scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

**Background**

After reading [this beautiful answer on how to extend ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319229/ggplot2-geom-text-resize-with-the-plot-and-force-fit-text-within-geom-bar) and [the corresponding vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html) I was trying to understand, how to extend `ggplot`.

**In a nutshell**

I understand, how the pieces are put together, but I am missing an important information: how does `ggplot` determine the default range for the axis?

**Code**

Consider the following toy example:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

GeomFit <- ggproto("GeomFit", GeomBar,
                   required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                   setup_data = .subset2(GeomBar, "setup_data"),
                   draw_panel = function(self, data, panel_scales, coord, width = NULL) {
                     bars <- ggproto_parent(GeomBar, self)$draw_panel(data,
                                                                      panel_scales, 
                                                                      coord)
                     coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_scales)    
                     tg <- textGrob("test", coords$x, coords$y * 2 - coords$ymin)
                     grobTree(bars, tg)
                   }
)

geom_fit <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                     stat = "count", position = "stack",
                     ...,
                     width = NULL,
                     binwidth = NULL,
                     na.rm = FALSE,
                     show.legend = NA,
                     inherit.aes = TRUE) {

  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = stat,
    geom = GeomFit,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      width = width,
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}

set.seed(1234567)
data_gd <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5], 
                      y = 1:5)

p <- ggplot(data = data_gd, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) + 
  geom_fit(stat = "identity")
```

Which produces this plot:
[image: Barplot with text]

**Problem**

As you can see, some text is not shown. I assume that `ggplot` somehow calculates the ranges for the axis and since it is not aware of the extra space needed for my `textGrob`. How can I solve that? (Desired outcome is equivalent to `p + expand_limits(y = 10)`

*NB.* Of course I could push the problem to the end user, by requiring to add a manual scale. But ideally I would like the scales to be set up properly.

Comment: `ggplot` expands the range of the data by multiplicatively and additively. The mult and add factors can set by the user in the `expand` argument of a `scale` function. [See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24831139/903061). This often comes up when people want [the plot to not be expanded at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22945857/903061). In recent versions, you can use [`expand_scale` to expand the axis in one direction only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52318514/903061). `?expand_scale` is a decent place to start.

Comment: I don't know how, internally, the initial axis range to be expanded is determined.(Which is why I'm just commenting, not answering.)

Comment: Based on my understanding, the scale range is trained based on the data range. If you check `layer_data(p)`, the y values range from 1-5, so that's the plot's scale range.

Comment: How does `ggplot` know for which range it has to look? With the same data, I can get quite different ranges based on my mapping: `d <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 10), y = sample(3, 100, TRUE))`: `p <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x)); p + geom_bar()` vs `p + geom_bar(aes(y=y), stat = "identity")`. So only after we know which mappings we use in the `geom` we can determine the range for the plot. -> 1. which function is responsible for determining the range? 2. from which function is his function called?

Comment: @thothal That would be the `train_position` function from [Layout](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/26cd1075006da8f12f30ace7fbf9883c595a38e3/R/layout.R). One trick I like to use when digging into ggplot objects is to run debug on `ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot` or `ggplot2:::ggplot_gtable.ggplot_built` (the two stages of `ggplotGrob()`), & check the output in each step to find where the phenomenon of interest (in this case scale creation) happens. Careful though, the rabbit hole can get really, really deep...

Comment: +1, that's what I am currently doing, so much to learn. And thanks to your other answer I was no able to use `debug` on some internal functions in the different `Geom*`. I think I found an ugly workaround, which I will post for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Eureka**

Found an ugly hack thanks to the awesome help of @Z.Lin on how to debug `ggplot` code. Here's how I came up with this rather ugly hack for future reference:

**How I got there**

While debugging `debug(ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot)` I learned that the culprit can be found somewhere in `FacetNull$train_scales` (in my plot with no facets, 
 other facets like `FacetGrid` work in a similiar manner). This I learned through `debug(environment(FacetNull$train_scales)$f)` which in turn I learned in the [answer by Z.Lin in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282193/call-setup-data-from-parent-class).

Once I was able to debug `ggproto` objects, I could see that in this very function the scales are trained. Basically the function looks at aesthetics which are relevant  the specific scale (no clue where this information is set up in the first place, any ideas anybody?) and looks which of these aesthetics are present in the layer data.

I saw that a field `ymax_final` (which is - according to [this table](https://yutannihilation.github.io/Rmd/ggplot2_generated.html) - only used for `stat_boxplot`) is among the ones which are considered for the setting up the scales. With this piece of information it was easy to find an ugly hack by setting this field in `setup_data` to the appropriate value.

**Code**

```
GeomFit <- ggproto("GeomFit", GeomBar,
                   required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                   setup_data = function(self, data, params) {
                      data <- ggproto_parent(GeomBar, self)$setup_data(data, params)
                      ## here's the hack: add a field which is not needed in this geom, 
                      ## but which is used by Facet*$train_scales which 
                      ## eventually sets up the scales
                      data$ymax_final <- 2 * data$y
                      data
                   }, 
                   draw_panel = function(self, data, panel_scales, coord, width = NULL) {
                     bars <- ggproto_parent(GeomBar, self)$draw_panel(data,
                                                                      panel_scales, 
                                                                      coord)
                     coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_scales)    
                     tg <- textGrob("test", coords$x, coords$y * 2 - coords$ymin)
                     grobTree(bars, tg)
                   }
)
```

**Result**

[image: Barplot with labels]

**Open Question**

Where are the (axis) scales set up if you do not define them by hand? I guess there the fields which are relevant for scaling are set up.